# Run sed for a range of lines FASTER

Tags: sed, line, selection

I have a file with millions of lines
And in a script I want to use the following line (which removes unprintable characters) in a loop for a given line range

```
sed -i $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' ~/test.txt
```

How do I do that ? It needs to run very fast

I've tried

```
sed -i $"{${line1},${line2}}{s/[^[:print:]\t]//g}" ~/test.txt
```

which is very slow for range of 1000 lines near the end of the file

Comment: What is the first `$` for? Isn't that too many curly braces?

Comment: @Cyrus – the syntax `$'…'` is interpreted by advanced shells like bash and zsh as a literal (see the QUOTING section of the bash man page, or search for `$'string'`). For example, `$'\n'` is a very reliable way of getting a newline character. In this case, it's ensuring sed sees a literal tab rather than an escaped `t`. Note that `$"…"` is _not_ similar, so @M.A.'s second code block leads with a (likely) unintended `$`

Comment: @AdamKatz: Thank you, I missed `\t`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of the composition of your test file (how many replacements are needed?), so I can't faithfully reproduce your test, but I'm using my /bin/bash (1168776 bytes in 5714 "lines", with 372073 (31.8%) printable/tab characters).

#### sed

(Baseline for timing purposes)

```
$ cp /bin/bash sh; time sed -i $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' sh
sed -i $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' sh  1.66s user 0.01s system 98% cpu 1.687 total
$ cp /bin/bash sh; time sed -i $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' sh
sed -i $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' sh  1.74s user 0.01s system 89% cpu 1.945 total
$ cp /bin/bash sh; time sed -i $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' sh
sed -i $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' sh  1.67s user 0.01s system 97% cpu 1.718 total
```

Mean average of total times = 1.783s  (it's important to run multiple times to control for caching. I ran four times and dropped the first to account for caching, then averaged to control for externalities like my web browser)

#### perl

I translated this to perl to see if that would be faster:

```
$ cp /bin/bash sh; time perl -i -pe $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' sh
perl -i -pe $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' sh  0.18s user 0.01s system 92% cpu 0.208 total
$ cp /bin/bash sh; time perl -i -pe $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' sh
perl -i -pe $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' sh  0.18s user 0.01s system 68% cpu 0.271 total
$ cp /bin/bash sh; time perl -i -pe $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' sh
perl -i -pe $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' sh  0.21s user 0.00s system 81% cpu 0.258 total
```

Mean average of total times = 0.246s ‍

However, I noticed some differences. GNU `sed` is struggling, perhaps due to either a different definition of the `[:print:]` class or (more likely) different handling of control characters:

```
$ sed $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' /bin/bash |head -c64 |hd
00000000  45 4c 46 3e 30 f6 40 48  ce 40 38 40 40 40 40 68  |ELF>0.@H.@8@@@@h|
00000010  68 a8 a8 a8 98 cd 98 cd  d0 d0 d0 8d d7 0a 8d d7  |h...............|
00000020  0a b0 b0 b0 30 57 30 57  f0 f0 23 f0 23 b9 a8 55  |....0W0W..#.#..U|
00000030  f0 3c f0 4c f0 4c c4 c4  c4 44 44 50 e5 74 64 30  |.<.L.L...DDP.td0|
00000040
$ perl -pe $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' /bin/bash |head -c64 |hd
00000000  45 4c 46 3e 30 40 48 40  38 40 40 40 40 68 68 30  |ELF>0@H@8@@@@hh0|
00000010  57 30 57 23 23 55 3c 4c  4c 44 44 50 74 64 30 49  |W0W##U<LLDDPtd0I|
00000020  30 49 30 49 44 44 51 74  64 52 74 64 23 23 2c 2c  |0I0IDDQtdRtd##,,|
00000030  2f 6c 69 62 36 34 2f 6c  64 2d 6c 69 6e 75 78 2d  |/lib64/ld-linux-|
00000040
```

See all those dots in the GNU `sed` output? Those are failures to replace content. I also observe these in Busybox `sed`. BSD `sed` (which is used by Mac OS X) does not appear to have this limitation, but note this for portability purposes as needed.

#### tr

```
$ cp /bin/bash sh; time tr -cd $'[ -~\t\n]' < sh > sh-tr && mv sh-tr sh
tr -cd $'[[:print:]\t]' < sh > sh-tr  0.00s user 0.01s system 62% cpu 0.012 total
$ cp /bin/bash sh; time tr -cd $'[ -~\t\n]' < sh > sh-tr && mv sh-tr sh
tr -cd $'[[:print:]\t]' < sh > sh-tr  0.00s user 0.01s system 81% cpu 0.009 total
$ cp /bin/bash sh; time tr -cd $'[ -~\t\n]' < sh > sh-tr && mv sh-tr sh
tr -cd $'[[:print:]\t]' < sh > sh-tr  0.00s user 0.01s system 82% cpu 0.012 total
```

Mean average of total times = 0.011s ⚡️

I've tested this with GNU `tr` and Busybox `tr` (they have equal performance). We're using `tr` to delete (`-d`) rather than **tr**anslate, and we're acting on the complement (`-c`) of the given class (`tr` does *not* use regex, so we can't invert the character class with a caret the way we can in `sed`).

Busybox `tr` does not support `$'[[:print:]\t]'` so I have converted it to a range from space to tilde (all printable lower-ASCII except tab and newline) and I added not just tab but also newline since `tr` needs to explicitly preserve that character (`sed` did not). If the lines don't match properly, consider adding `\r` to the replacement set.

`strings` is also good here, but it does not preserve lines (it replaces each contiguous string of non-printable characters with a newline)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I run it on my txt file, it reduced the number of lines and gave me the same time as my sed command

Comment: "It" being the `strings` command, or the `perl` command? I'm also running GNU `sed`. I just tried it with BSD `sed` (which is what OS X has) and it does indeed remove all of the items GNU leaves behind. I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: I ran the strings command, I'm running it in busybox linux, so the stuff I can do is limited. Also I need the lines to be the same after the command because I'm using the line numbers as variables in the script

Comment: Busybox `sed` gives me a lot of null characters when I run it with the `$'…'` quoting format. Since it can understand `\t`, I suggest migrating to the `'…'` quoting format. `strings` won't work for you given your need to keep lines consistent. I have another idea that I'll add to my answer.

Comment: Okay, I've added a _much_ faster solution using `tr` and confirmed that it works in Busybox.

Comment: I really appreciate your solution to this. But weirdly I get the same performance as the sed command...
real    0m 56.97s.
This is how I ran the command
time tr -cd $'[ -~\t\n]' < test.txt > test.txt-tr && mv test.txt-tr test.txt
Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong
Thanks again
BTW the system is busybox running in an ARM processor in a SOC platform

Comment: This might be entirely I/O. What about when you run `time cat test.txt >/dev/null`? That'll be your best-case scenario.